# react reverse proxy nginx, running using subdirectory

Tags: reactjs, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

So I have a Docker container running a quizapp that serves a `create react app` React app that is run using `npm run start`. It works locally (I could port forward the port and the host can access the application just fine). I'd like to deploy this to my remote server that has Nginx as reverse proxy. I already have the `/` location used for something else so I figured I'd use another location. So I made the following in `sites-available`:

```
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6789/;
        }

        location /someotherapp/ {
                rewrite ^/smallblog/(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_set_header Host              $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Prefix /smallblog;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
            proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        }

        location /quizapp {
                rewrite ^/quizapp/(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_set_header Host              $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Prefix /quizapp;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3500/;
            proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        }
```

But this didn't work, when I access `mypublicipaddress/quizapp` it shows a blank white page. For reference I have another Flask app (with subdirectory `/myotherapp` above) and it works just fine. But, if I set the React app to use the `/` location i.e. like this:

```
        location /quizapp/ {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3500/;
        }
```

then it works just fine. I don't understand what I did wrong. For reference, my `App.js` looks like this:

```
function App() {

  return (
    <Router basename='/'>
      <Container maxWidth="sm">
        <Box textAlign="center" mt={5}>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<>
              <Typography variant="h2" fontWeight="bold">
                Quiz app
              </Typography>
              <Settings /></>
            } />
            <Route path="/questions" element={<Questions />} />
            <Route path="/finalscreen" element={<FinalScreen />} />
          </Routes>
        </Box>
      </Container>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Any ideas?